# VIM open url plug grab line

Tags: vim

So I'm kinda new to VIM and love it so far but currently trying to add a custom command for the plugin ["vim-open-url"](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-open-url) so currently it's looking like below.

```
nnoremap <C-i> :OpenURL http://localhost...?grep=<cword><CR>
```

So what I'm trying to do is getting a test name and open that in my browser and specify that test with the grep.

Example of a test line is:

```
it('should do something ... test', function() {
```

And currently it's grabbing the single word that I'm standing on, so it would be "grep=something" but I need the full text between the single quotes. So to the question!

How do I make my "awesome" line of custom command grab the full text between the single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim only provides `<cword>` and `<cWORD>`; for anything else you need a different approach.

The "correct" approach would be extracting the text inside the single quotes with `matchstr(getline('.'), "'\\zs[^']\\+\\ze'")`. For a better emulation of the built-ins, you'd also need to ensure that the cursor actually is inside the quotes (using the `\%#` atom matching at the cursor position with `search()`). If there is no quoted string, an error message should be printed. All of this requires multiple lines of code, so we're now talking about a custom `:function` to be invoked by your mapping. I would go this route for a robust plugin implementation.

Libraries like my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) can simplify this, in this case with `ingo#text#frompattern#GetAroundHere()`

#### Shortcut

If you're fine with clobbering the default register, we can let the *inner quote text object* (`i'`) do most of the work. Adapt you mapping to first `yi'`, and then insert the register contents, either directly in command-line mode via `<C-r>`:

```
nnoremap <C-i> yi':OpenURL http://localhost...?grep=<C-r>"<CR>
```

Alternatively, we can interpolate the register (`@"`) into the command-line via `:execute`:

```
nnoremap <C-i> yi':execute 'OpenURL http://localhost...?grep=' . @"<CR>
```